# What is the right way to install nodejs on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I want to install nodejs and the npm packages on my system. My final goal is to install MJML.

I followed the steps found on the [nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But after I run `nodejs` command on the terminal I get

```
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Similarly when I run `node`:

```
The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

So, what's the right way to install it?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` after running the script?

Comment: No, I didn't... I can see the package is install on "/usr/bin" though.

Comment: Do you see that node.js is installed in /usr/bin, but Bash doesn't find it? Did you try closing Bash and re-opening it?

Comment: I followed those instructions, and I successfully installed node.js 9.x on Ubuntu 16.04.03.

Answer (score 1):

Please type this command on terminal.

```
             sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

To check the version of Node js

```
             nodejs -v
```

To remove the Node js

```
             sudo apt autoremove
```